# Check if change directory command is executed properly in batch file windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing, cd

I'm working on a batch file script where my requirement is to traverse into the folder from the current directory and delete some files.

What happens is if the path is not found it starts deleting files from the wrong location.

Here my script

```
set BuildPath="%CD%"
set DrivePath="%CD:~0,3%"

cd "%BuildPath%\Mac\Data\"
del * /S /Q
rmdir /S /Q "%BuildPath%\Mac\Data\"
```

Now what happens in the above script is if **"%BuildPath%\Mac\Data\"** is not found it will start deleting files from the wrong folder because the cd command did not work.

What I want to check is whether the changing directory was successful or not. if it was not successful then I don't want to perform any action.

Comment: Instead of just asking questions to one of the solution providers, please show me the courtesy of providing feedback on on my answer! Not only does my footnote exactly answer your question, `What I want to check is whether the changing directory was successful or not. if it was not successful then I don't want to perform any action.`, it also provides replacement code much more efficiently/succinctly. If there is something about it you dislike or wish me to clarify then do so. You're not new here and should show more respect to someone who's taken time to try to help you with your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
PUSHD u:\sourcedir
set "BuildPath=%CD%"
set "DrivePath=%CD:~0,3%"

cd "%BuildPath%\Mac\Data"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO fail cd
IF /i "%cd%" neq "%BuildPath%\Mac\Data" echo FAIL&GOTO :EOF 
ECHO del * /S /Q
ECHO rmdir /S /Q "%BuildPath%\Mac\Data\"
popd

GOTO :EOF
```

Note : `U:\sourcedir` is my test directory.

If the `cd` is successful, `errorlevel` will be `0` so the `fail cd` message will *not* be issued. `cd` after the change will contain the same path as specified (I omit the trailing backslash).

On the other hand, if the change is not successful (directory does not exist), `errorlevel` will become `1` and the `fail cd` message will be produced, and `cd` will not be as specified.

So two methods here - `errorlevel` and `compare-directory-name`. This is a reason for assigning strings using `set "var=value"` syntax, where the number and position of rabbit's ears can be controlled.

Comment: It always echo's FAIL. Not sure why. Let me tell you there will different folders and files inside the "%BuildPath%\Mac\Data" directory

Comment: Well, I tried the code with `\mac\data` present and absent as a subdirectory of `u:\sourcedir` and also attempting to use `\mac\data1` which of course didn't exist. It acted precisely as I expected. Perhaps if you were to set `echo` to `on` you would be able to see the difference between the two strings that the `if /i` is comparing. You don't comment about any report from the `echo fail cd` line.

Comment: I'm not clear about PUSHD u:\sourcedir ? what is that. I don't want to keep any static path in between? Can you explain me about it? Thanks

Comment: `PUSHD u:\sourcedir` changes the current directory to `u:\sourcedir` which, as I noted, is my test directory. This saves the *current* directory on a stack, then switches to the target directory. When the companion instruction `popd` is executed, the last-saved-to-stack directory is restored as current. The effective result, for this code is that the current directory is changed to `u:\sourcedir` where I can create (or not create) the directory that the code is expected to detect, and when the report has been generated, return to the original directory.

Comment: It's not relevant in your case where you have your own start directory..

Answer (score 0):

Your script unnecessarily sets a variable to the name of an existing variable before setting a variable which is not used at all. It then deletes all of the files in the current tree before removing all of the directories, when removing the directories alone should do it.

The following single line batch script should do the same as your script and only do so if the location exists!

```bat
@CD /D "%__CD__%Mac\Data" 2>Nul && RD /S /Q "%__CD__%Mac\Data">Nul 2>&1
```

The command following the `&&` operator is only ran if the command immediately prior to it returned as successful.